# Am getting this popup in the live back-end server, how can i get rid of this plz!

Tags: magento-1.9

Latest Message: New Patch for PayPal Instant Payment Notification (IPN) Changes. Upgrade to 1.9.3.3 or SUPEE-8167 by June 30, 2017 to Avoid Service Disruptions – 6/13/2017 Read details

Can i know how to upgrade it?

Comment: Welcome to Magento SE. What exactly is your problem? This is a message from the Magento news feed. Did you read the details? Are you having trouble to understand it? Or did you already update/patch and want to know how to mark the message as read?

Comment: Hi, actually i want to solve this with no other further issues.Cos had tried to add the patch once but resulted in many issues in my website regarding payments. And am using PayFort for payment.

Answer (score 1):

You can mark it as read  or remove it in the message section.
Or, you can upgrade to 1.9.3.3  or install patch SUPEE-8167

Comment: If i remove it in the message section, will it not create any issues further.
Can i get any permanent solution plz

Comment: It's telling you that you need to install the patch or upgrade (if you use PayPal as a payment method). That is the permanent solution. If you do use Paypal and don't patch or upgrade you will not receive notifications from Paypal when customers pay. I'm afraid I don't know any more than that. If you just remove it in the message section then the issue will still remain.

Comment: Am using PayFort for the payment, PayPal is just as it is and am not using it at all. But even then am getting this message. Why so?

Comment: It's just an automatic message. It appeared because you haven't applied the patch. If you don't want or need the patch just remove the message and carry on as normal.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.
Hope so it will not cause any major issues to my website!!

Comment: I don't think it will if you're not using paypal. If the answer helped you and you think it was correct you can accept it. Or not, it's up to you :)